# Quantum Noise Dataset

Tags: machine-learning

Does anyone in here know of an open source source for finding noisy data from quantum gates. I am interested in playing around with in the same way people play around with MNIST.

I know it's a long shot, but I hope to hear back from someone!

Comment: Hi! Could you clarify what you mean by finding noisy data from quantum gates? Do you mean the error associated with a gate?

Comment: If you know what you're after specifically, and you know what you're doing, you could always make the data yourself using, for instance, qiskit and the IBM Q experience. You could get a lot of help on this website to get you started too, but the question needs to be much less broad, and we would need more info on what you mean by 'noisy data from quantum gates' (as @met927 already pointed out)

Comment: Also, if you're interested in noise models for quantum gates you might be interested in [this workbook](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/3_building_noise_models.html), which shows how to work with noise models within qiskit. You can even import the noise 'models' of the actual systems from IBM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about quantum gates but here is a link to some ressources of a company which produces randomness using light noise (should be the same principle), you can maybe find something looking at some technical data or white papers [here](https://www.idquantique.com/resource-library/random-number-generation/)